# Create Mac executable that can be executed on other users' computers without them using chmod

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, bash, executable

I'm new to xcode and I wrote a C++ command line executable on Xcode but for some reason when double-clicking the excutable file it has a few problems:
1. the working directory is not set to the directory the executable is in so it doesn't open any of the relative files that's with the executable
2. when copying onto another computer the user needs to open the terminal and change the permission in order to execute it

I made a work around for problem 1 by making a bash command script that will change the current directory and exec the command line executable. But the script also does exhibits problem 2.

So are there any solutions to these problems?

Comment: How are you copying the file to the other system? If you are using FTP, or a FAT32 filesystem or something else that doesn't have the concept of an executable, it will not preserve the `execute` bit when copying.

Comment: its on a cloud server